# Doubly robust learning with same features influencing treatment and outcome

Tags: machine-learning, python, causality, treatment-effect, doubly-robust-estimator

I'm looking at some of the examples in the econML package for double machine learning. Specifically, the example found [here](https://econml.azurewebsites.net/spec/estimation/dr.html#usage-faqs) (code below).
In the example **W** is the features which might influence both the choice of treatment and the
outcome.
**X** is the features which might influence how effective the treatment is, i.e. the end goal is to be able to estimate the treatment effect as a function of **X**.

The issue is that all of my features might influence both treatment and outcome, i.e. **W** and **X** represent the same set of features. Can I simply set `X = W` in the below example, or will I need some other approach?

```
from econml.dr import DRLearner
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor, RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
model_reg = lambda: GridSearchCV(
                estimator=RandomForestRegressor(),
                param_grid={
                        'max_depth': [3, None],
                        'n_estimators': (10, 50, 100)
                    }, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'
                )
model_clf = lambda: GridSearchCV(
                estimator=RandomForestClassifier(min_samples_leaf=10),
                param_grid={
                        'max_depth': [3, None],
                        'n_estimators': (10, 50, 100)
                    }, cv=5, n_jobs=-1, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error'
                )
est = DRLearner(model_regression=model_reg(), model_propensity=model_clf(),
                model_final=model_reg(), cv=5)
est.fit(y, T, X=X, W=W)
point = est.effect(X, T0=T0, T1=T1)
```

Comment: Yes, variables that affect both the treatment and outcome are called confounders and are pretty much what causal inference is about. The two options are just in case you might know a priori that some variables only affect the treatment or outcome.